# How to strech the rectangle shaped image in the four corners?

Tags: android

My requirment is i need to select an image with group of people and  i need  to select a person or persons and i need to crop that particular selected part of the image ,for this i took a rectangle shaped transparent image  ,and i will place this  rectangle shaped image on the actual image i want to crop and now where i screwed up,i want that rectangle image to be streched by pulling at the corners and select the actual image ,can any one help me how to strech the image by pulling at the corners

Comment: Show what you did? Code snippet!

Comment: if you want to strech the image by pulling at the corners use imgview.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to draw your bitmap to a canvas  and then manage the user interactions from there. you can stretch you images to any size in a canvas by using

```
canvas.drawBitmapMesh(bitmap, 1, 1,
                                        vertices, 0, null, 0,
                                        paint);
```

Change your vertices  accordingly. [see docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmapMesh%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20float%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%5B%5D,%20int,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)

The best way to do this is by creating a custom view  and override onDraw and then do your drawing here.